# A question about interval operation result in a game

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, interval-arithmetic

A state is:$A_{q}=(A_{q}^{0},...,A_{q}^{E})$ where $A_{i}^{j}$ is interval, $q$ and $E$ are positive integer

The initial state is $A_{m}=((0,1),\emptyset...,\emptyset)$ , $m>E$

Procedure：
Every time before asking a question, randomly select a number x between 0 and 1, interval $T=(0,x)$

(here the original problem is ask question and then answer yes or no, i think we can skip understand original problem)

A 'Yes' answer will result in a new state $A_{q-1}$: $^{y}A_{q-1}=(^{y}A_{q-1}^{0},...,^{y}A_{q-1}^{E})$ with

$^{y}A_{q-1}^{e}=(A^{e}_{q}\cap T)\cup (A^{e-1}_{q}-T)$  for $1 \le e \le E$

and

$^{y}A_{q-1}^{0} = A_{q}^{0} \cap T$

A 'No' answer will result in a new state $A_{q-1}$: $^{n}A_{q-1}=(^{n}A_{q-1}^{0},...,^{n}A_{q-1}^{E})$ with

$^{n}A_{q-1}^{e}=(A^{e}_{q}- T)\cup (A^{e-1}_{q}\cap T)$  for $1 \le e \le E$

and

$^{n}A_{q-1}^{0} = A_{q}^{0} - T$

Ask m questions (repeat the procedure m times) in total, and finally get the state $A_{0}$

The question is that one paper says that :

"The set $\cup_{e=0}^{E}A_{0}^{e}$ consists of a finite number of intervals $I_{1}, I_{2},.. I_{r}$ (where $r\leq E+1$). Define $depth(I_{j})$ to be the number of sets $A^{e}_{0}$, $0\le e\le E$, that intersect $I_{j}$, and define $depth(A_{0})=\sum^{r}_{j=1} depth(I_{j})$. Using the fact that $A_{0}=(A_{0}^{0},...,A_{0}^{E})$ can be described completely by no more than $E+1$ previous 'Yes' answers and $E+1$ previous 'No' answers, it's not hard to see that $depth(A_{0})\le E+1$."

I cannot understand :

1. Why r must be $\le E+1$
2. Why $A_{0}$ can be described completely by no more than $E+1$ previous 'Yes' answers and $E+1$ previous 'No' answers, it's not hard to see that $depth(A_{0})\le E+1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $A_q^0$ can only be $(0,1), T, (0,1)-T, \emptyset$.

More specifically:
$$A_m^0=(0,1)$$
If the answer to the first question is 'yes', then:
$$A_{m-1}^0=T$$
else it's:
$$A_{m-1}^0=(0,1)-T$$
Note that $T\cap ((0,1)-T)=((0,1)-T)\cap T=\emptyset$, as after a 'yes' the set only contains elements of $T$ and after a 'no' it doesn't contain any.

So if the answers given oppose, then for $k\gt1$:

$$A_{m-k}^0=\emptyset$$

Comment: Thank u for answering my question! Sorry, i didn't express the question clearly. Each time the interval T changes since every time the x is randomly chosen again before ask a new question. I just edited my question. Do u have any new idea? maybe ur hint can still work in this case, i'm thinking about it.

Comment: that's pretty much a completely different question!

Comment: I know, but maybe as u mentioned, the $A_{q}^{0}$ should change to $\emptyset$ or some form.

Comment: it might, why isn't the question for $T=(min(x,y),max(x,y))$ aswell?

Comment: I don't understand. change the form of $T$?

Comment: is there a reason $T$ always starts at $(0$, can't it start anywhere?

Comment: $T$ always start at $(0$, in the form of the (0,x). This is the game rule during the game.

Comment: when simply use induction method, assume $r \leq E+1$, the next question comes, the number of intervals will still increase, can not get after this question $r still \leq E+1$. so maybe there is sth because of the form of the state. Actually when i do some simulation, the first several $A_{0}^{e}$ of $A_{0}$ are always $\emptyset$

Comment: it seems quite likely they will be $\emptyset$, but there are possibilities that won't do this, for example $x=0.25$ and $x=0.75$ answering no then yes returns the interval $(0.25,0.75)$

Comment: yeah! just in high probability $A_{q}^{0}$ is $\emptyset$, so when $A_{q}^{0}$ is not $\emptyset$, then each time x must be in the $A_{q+k}^{0}$ in the previous questions. if this happen, then $A^{1}_{q},...A^{E}_{q}$ may have  a special form and now $r$ must be $\leq E+1$ (just guess, haha, i haven't figured it out)

Comment: so have you answered your question then?

Comment: Not yet....sigh, still confused. Anyway, thank u for ur help!